# How to use ! in the sed command?

Tags: sed, escape-characters, csh, special-characters

Apologize if you feel this question very basic. Anyways, I am typing
`sed '/[iI]t/ a\\
Found it!' data` but it says the error event not found.

I tried escaping that `!` with  backslash `\!` but it doesn't work.

I don't understand when backslash `\` can escape a character and use it literally then why doesn't it work in sed?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: @StephenHarris C Shell. I know Bash is better, but can't I work on Csh?

Comment: What's the `a//` bit for? `echo blah | sed 'a\\<NL>!'` appends a `!` without issue in `csh`... (where `<NL>` is a literal newline).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a special character as a normal one?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296147)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which OS did you try it on? On HP-UX 8.11 csh there are 2 ways to cancel the speacial meaning of exclamation mark for history substitutions (see History substitutions in man csh).

1. Put space after ! (couple of other characters work too)

   ```
   sed '/[iI]t/ a\\
   Found it! ' data
   ```
2. Escape it via \!

   ```
   sed '/[iI]t/ a\\
   Found it\!' data
   ```

   This actually also works with double quotes:

   ```
   sed "/[iI]t/ a\\
   Found it\!" data
   ```