# Replace "_" with ":" using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to replace `_` with `:` in a file on a Unix system using `sed`:

```
sed "s/'_''/:/g"
```

However, it doesn't work. I cannot find a solution in similar sed related posts.

Comment: Related: [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/170373) and maybe also [What characters need to be escaped in files without quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347332/170373)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra single quote, and, in fact, don't need the quotes at all.  The underscore and the colon are not significant to the shell.  You are asking `sed` to match `'_''` (all four characters) and replace them with a colon.

```
$ echo "_This is a test_" | sed s/_/:/g  
:This is a test:
```

Not that quotes aren't a good idea...

Comment: Also, more efficient: `sed 'y/_/:/'`, or even `tr '_' ':'` (or just `tr _ :` if you want to save on typing).

Comment: The double quotes are not necessary, the stream presented to `sed` in the example is the same in any case.  I would agree that if there were shell metacharacters in the stream, like a glob, you'd have a problem, but then add a comment explaining it.