# How to delete a filename ":?"

Tags: bash, filenames, rm, scp

I create a file name `:~` on bash shell by accident

```
scp foo :~
```

How to delete it?

Comment: Is the file called `:~` (as in question) or `:?` (as in title)?

Answer (score 2):

try `rm ':?'` or `rm ":?"` or `rm :\?`

mainly you need to quote the file name either with single quotes or double quotes. Or escape any special characters contains in files name.

some special characters I can count are:

```
*
|
$
&
#
<>
;
space/tab/newline
\
brackets/parenthesis/braces
'"`
?
etc
```

I suggest to use single quotes to prevent deleting a wrong file named `my_file` instead of `$file` with `rm $file` or `rm "$file"` when `file='my_file'`. The single quote character is the only character that you can't quote with single quotes in Bourne-like shells, but you can always quote the rest of the file name with `'...'` and `'` itself as `\'`:

```
rm -- '-$#~<>'\''"*?[]{}'`
```

Note that `-` is not special to the shell, but it's special to `rm` in that if found at the start of an argument, it's treated as an option. Here the `--` tells `rm` that the arguments that follow are not to be treated as options even if they start with a `-`.

Comment: I would also use the `-i` flag just to make sure you're deleting the proper file.

Comment: More on that at [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141)

Answer (score -1):

In general, whenever you want to remove a weirdly-named file, you can try to use the marker `--` which denotes the end of options. Anything after that flag is handled as a positional parameter. (See also: [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash) )

So, that would be

```
rm -i -- :?
```

(As suggested by @Doug O'Neal, the `-i` option prompts you before deletion to make sure you're removing the correct file.)

However, in this case `?` will be expanded by the shell as a glob character. So the above won't work.

In this case, you can use the autocomplete feature of the shell. Go into the directory where the weirdly-named file is, then type `rm :` (without pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through all files in the current directory. The weirdly-named file will appear properly quoted.

Comment: `--` is a marker for `rm`, not Bash. And it doesn't do anything to avoid the `?` being treated as a glob character.