# What characters need to be escaped when using the printf command?

Tags: shell, posix, printf

I want to clarify that I am not talking about how to escape characters on the shell level of interpretation.

As far as I can tell, only two character need to be escaped: `%` and `\`

To print a literal `%`, you must escape it with a preceding `%`:

```
printf '%%'
```

To print a literal `\` you must escape it with a preceding `\`:

```
printf '\\'
```

Are there any other instances where I would need to escape a character for it to be interpreted literally?

Comment: looks like `\' \" \?`     .......... a good search engine for this kind of stuff is http://symbolhound.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the format argument of `printf`, only the `%` and `\` characters are special (no, `"` is not special and `\"` is unspecified per POSIX).

But, two **important** notes.

1. In most `printf` implementations¹, it's the byte values for `\` and `%` that are special and the POSIX specification could even be interpreted as requiring it as  it requires the `printf` utility to be an interface to the `printf(3)` C function and not `wprintf(3)` for instance (like [it requires `%.3s` to truncate to 3 bytes and not 3 characters](/q/350240)).

   In some character encodings including BIG5 and GB18030, there are hundreds of characters that contain the encoding of backslash, and to *escape* those for `printf`, you'd need to insert a `\` before each `0x5c` byte within the encoding of those characters!

   For instance in BIG5-HKSCS, as used for instance in the `zh_HK.big5hkscs` (Hong Kong) locale, all of `Ěαжふ㘘㙡䓀䨵䪤么佢俞偅傜兝功吒吭园坼垥塿墦声娉娖娫嫹嬞孀尐岤崤幋廄惝愧揊擺暝枯柦槙檝歿汻沔涂淚滜潿瀙瀵焮燡牾狖獦珢珮琵璞疱癧礒稞穀笋箤糭綅縷罡胐胬脪苒茻莍蓋蔌蕚螏螰許豹贕赨跚踊蹾躡鄃酀酅醆鈾鎪閱鞸餐餤駹騱髏髢髿鱋鱭黠﹏` contain byte 0x5c (which is also the encoding of `\`).

   With most `printf` implementations, in that locale, `printf 'αb'` doesn't output `αb` but byte `0xa3` (the first byte of the encoding of `α`) followed by the BS character (the expansion of `\b`).

   ```
   $ LC_ALL=zh_HK.big5hkscs luit
   $ locale charmap
   BIG5-HKSCS
   $ printf 'αb' | LC_ALL=C od -tx1 -tc
   0000000  a3  08
           243  \b
   0000002
   ```

   Best is to avoid using (and even installing / making available) those locales as they cause all sorts of bugs and vulnerabilities of that sort.
2. Some `printf` implementations support options, and even those that don't are required to support `--` as the option delimiter. So `printf --` won't output `--` but likely report an error about a missing format argument. So if you can't guarantee your *format* won't start with `-`, you have to use the `--` option delimiter:

   ```
    printf -- "$escaped_format" x y...
   ```

In any case, if you want to print arbitrary strings, you'd use:

```
printf '%s\n' "$data" # with terminating newline
printf %s "$data"     # without
```

There's no character that is special in the string passed to `%s` (though note that with the exception of the `printf` builtin of `zsh`, you can't pass the NUL character in any of `printf` arguments).

Note that while the canonical way to enter a literal `\` is with `\\` and a literal `%` with `%%`, on ASCII-based systems, you can also use `\134` and `\45` and with some `printf` implementations `\x5c`, `\x25`, or `\x{5c}`, `\x{25}`, or (even on non-ASCII systems): `\u005c`, `\u0025` or `\u{5c}`, `\u{25}`.

---

<sup>¹ `yash`'s `printf` builtin being the only exception I am aware of.</sup>

Comment: "POSIX requires it to be an interface to printf(3)..." -- that's a bit funny in that the C `printf()` _doesn't_ interpret backslash-escapes, but it's the compiler that does. Which doesn't make those ASCII-incompatible charsets less of a problem of course.

Comment: @ilkkachu, yes the idea is that it requires its argument to be interpreted as arrays of bytes as opposed to text strings, like `%.3s` is meant to truncate to 3 bytes, not 3 characters. POSIX doesn't say in so many words that the format has to be interpreted as an array of bytes though. (and yes the handling of backslash there has nothing to do with the C `printf`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas "Some printf implementations support options, and even those that don't are required to support -- as the option delimiter. " `printf` does not adhere to the XBD Utility Syntax Guidelines- I didn't think POSIX required `printf` to support the `--` end of options delimter

Comment: @HaroldFischer, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_04 *Standard utilities that do not accept options, but that do accept operands, shall recognize "--" as a first argument to be discarded.*...

Comment: What about this: `!!` I get odd messages when I run a `printf` from the terminal that contains a double exclamation point `!!` in the string.

Comment: @Seamus, that would be history expansion done by your shell, not to do with `printf`. See [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141) for that.

Answer (score 3):

From the manual:

```
$ man printf
...
   printf FORMAT [ARGUMENT]...
...
   FORMAT controls the output as in C printf.  Interpreted sequences are:
```

This lists several interpreted sequences. The following are those where the character itself needs to be escaped.

```
   \"     double quote
   \\     backslash
   %%     a single %
```

I tested these three in `bash`, and they behaved as expected. As per `man bash`, this implementation of `printf` uses the "standard printf(1) format specifications" as above, in addition to a few more that aren't relevant here.

---

However, other shells such as `zsh` implement `printf` slightly differently. Here, the double quote shouldn't be escaped.

```
$ printf '"'
"   
$ printf '\"'
\"
```

Comment: Yeah, same behavior here on dash and bash. For what it's worth, the dash manual makes no mention of needing the to escape `"`, but maybe I'm not reading in between the lines

Comment: @HaroldFischer Presumably dash just inherits printf(1) too? I found the `zsh` manual a bit more opaque, so I didn't quote it here.

Comment: (edited) backslash-dquote is only needed if the format string is in dquotes, which is usually a bad idea, as then you also need to backslash backquote and (most) dollarsign, and _may_ need to _quadruple_ backslash if followed by a printf special. `printf` is _builtin_ in bash and dash, but like all nonspecial builtins in a POSIX shell must also be present as an 'external' program.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, the question does say `I want to clarify that I am not talking about how to escape characters on the shell level of interpretation`.

Comment: The [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/printf.html) lists only `\\ `, `\a`, `\b`, `\f`, `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, `\v` and `\nnn`, leaving others unspecified, in particular those `\"` and `\'`, which would be valid escapes in C. (That first one is the double backslash, of course, the space isn't part of it, I blame the sucky formatting in comments)

Comment: Assuming this question is about outputting some supplied data: No character has to be escaped in a special way (apart from from the shell) if `printf` is used properly.  For example:`printf '%s\n' '\'`, or `printf '%s\n' '%'`.  Data should not go in the format argument.

Comment: @Kusalananda: What is improper about this?: `printf '--- end log entry ---\n'`

Comment: @Seamus Nothing? Unless you want the output to contain the character sequence `\n` rather than a literal newline. If you want `\n` in the output, you could do `printf '--- end log entry ---%s' '\n'`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Oh, sorry - I should have been more explicit. My `printf` command (and yours), both throw an error: `-bash: printf: --: invalid option`

Comment: @Seamus In `bash`, yes, and I tested it in `zsh` where it doesn't error out. So make the problematic part a string that you format with `%s`: `printf '%s\n' '--- end log entry ---'`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Perfect! :))  'tho I still think it's a bit of an "odd duck". I'll **guess** that `zsh` didn't have the *legacy* to deal with that seems to be the point of item 2. in [the answer above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/552358/286615)??