# Use backslash or single-quotes for field separation

Tags: shell, awk, quoting

I have always been using single-quotes for the field separation like: `awk -F';' ...`

Quite new to me is the way of using a backslash like: `awk -F\; ...`

is there a technical difference for either, or is it just a matter of preference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's all to do with your shell, not with `awk`.

In Bourne-like shells, `\`, `'...'` and `"..."` are all quoting operators.

Quoting removes the special meaning a character may have in the syntax of the shell. `\` quotes a single character (except for newline which it removes instead), `'...'` and `"..."` can quote more than one (with `"..."` not *quoting* every character).

`;` is a special character in the syntax of the shell. It's used to separate commands. You want to quote it if you want to pass it verbatim to a command.  `\;`, `';'` will do.

`";"` will also do as `;` is not one of those characters that are still special within double quotes, but you'd need `"\\"` to pass one literal backslash to a command because `\` is one of those characters that are still special within `"..."` (though it's then only special when followed by other special characters within `"..."` like that `"` itself).

Again that very much depends on the shell. In the `rc` shell for instance, `\` and `"` are not special let alone quoting characters, `-F\;` wouldn't work there as the command would be parsed as both the `awk -F\`  and `...` command separated with `;`.

See [How to use a special character as a normal one?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141) for more details.

To complicates things further, note that the argument to `-F` itself **also** goes through one or two layers of backslash processing **by awk**.

`awk` processes first the argument it receives to expand ANSI C escape sequences in it. If you use `awk -F '\t'` or `awk -F \\t` or `awk -F "\\t"` or `awk -F "\t"`, `awk` receives an argument that contains `\t`, which it expands to a TAB character. The `FS` awk variable will contain a TAB character, not `\t`.

With `awk -F '\\'`, `awk` receives a `\\` argument and sets `FS` to the `\` character. Strictly speaking, `awk -F '\'` would is unspecified as that escape sequence is unfinished but in practice, except for busybox `awk`,  all `awk` implementations I know treat it the same as `awk -F '\\'`.

In `awk`, when `FS` contains a single character, that character is the field separator. `awk -F .` splits the records on dot characters.

However when `FS` contains more than one character, it is interpreted as a regular expression. `awk -F ..` doesn't spilt on sequences of two dots, but on sequences of any two characters as `.` is the regular expression operator that matches any single character. To split on two dots, you'd need `awk -F '[.][.]'` or `awk -F '\\.\\.'`.

With `awk -F '\\\\'`, a literal `\\\\` is passed by the shell to `awk`, `awk` expands each of those two `\\` to `\`, so `FS` becomes `\\`, which is treated as a regular expression. `\` is also special in the regular expression syntax and is used to remove the special meaning of a character **as a regex operator** this time. So again, that is splitting on backslash characters, though this time, as a regular expression.

So, in practice, to split on `\`, all of these (in Bourne-like shells) will work:

```
awk -F '\'      # FS becomes a single \ except in busybox where it's empty
awk -F "\\"     # instead so it's a one-character split on backslash
awk -F \\       # and a one-field-by-character split in busybox

awk -F '\\'     # FS becomes a single \ in every awk implementation
awk -F \\\\     # so one-character split on backslash
awk -F "\\\\"

awk -F '\\\'    # FS is \ on busybox and \\ in other implementations
awk -F \\\\\\   # so one-character split on backslash in busybox and
awk -F "\\\\\\" # \\ regex split in other implementations, to the same effect

awk -F '\\\\'     # FS is \\ in all implementations so
awk -F \\\\\\\\   # \\ regex split
awk -F "\\\\\\\"
```

I would advise to use single quotes as they are the most straightforward and least surprising kind of quotes. So here, to split on backslash portably: `awk -F '\\'`.

You can also do things like:

```
 awk -v FS='\\' ...
```

Or

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\"} ...'
```

or

```
awk ... 'FS=\\'
```

or:

```
FS='\' awk 'BEGIN{FS = ENVIRON["FS"]} ...'
```

(that one avoiding the extra backslash expansion performed by `awk`, so need only one backslash).

Answer (score 4):

All characters within single quotes are treated literally (i.e. no character is special between a pair of single quotes). Without single quotes, you need to backslash-escape a character with a special meaning if you want to use the literal character.

These are the quoting rules of the shell and are unrelated to awk.

Comment: so if the field separator would not be a special character lets say it was a `,` one could also just use a command like: `awk -F, ...`?

Comment: Yes, that's right.