# replacing single quotes with double quote in a file

Tags: sed

I need to replace all single quotes ' contained in /tmp/myfile with " (double quotes)

I'm using this

```
sed -i 's/'/\"/g' /tmp/myfile
```

and other combinations but I cannot find a way which works.

Any help please.

Comment: In case you have access to GNU sed, you could just do: `sed 's/\x27/"/g'` where `\x27` is the hex sequence for a single quote.

Comment: without GNU sed, create a file(say cmds) with this line: `s/'/"/g` Then invoke sed as: `sed -f cmds`

Answer (score 15):

To replace *single quotes* (`'`) it's easiest to put the sed command within *double* quotes and escape the double quote in the replacement:

```
$ cat quotes.txt 
I'm Alice
$ sed -e "s/'/\"/g"  quotes.txt 
I"m Alice
```

Note that the single quote is *not* special within double quotes, so it must not be escaped.

If, instead one wants to replace *backticks* (`` ` ``), as the question originally mentioned, they can be used as-is within single quotes:

```
$ cat ticks.txt
`this is in backticks`
$ sed -e 's/`/"/g'  ticks.txt
"this is in backticks"
```

Within double quotes, you'd need to escape the backtick with a backslash, since otherwise it starts an old-form command substitution.

See also:

- [What is the difference between "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/170373)
- [How to use a special character as a normal one?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141/170373)

Comment: Also, `y/'/"/` in `sed` for transliterating between two sets of characters efficiently.

Comment: Thank you , yes I wanted say "single quotes" to "double quotes"

Comment: If you still want the absolute robustness of single-quotes (which are different and *safer* and *simpler* than double-quotes in all Bourne-family-tree shells), the correct way to escape a single quote inside single quotes is `'\''`. (End single-quoting, backslash-escape a single single-quote, resume single-quoting.) Memorize it. Burn it into your mind. It will make your life better, and everyone else's life better, and the world as a whole better, etc.

Answer (score 8):

With bash, you cannot embed a single quote in a single quoted string, no matter how you try to escape it.

Some options:

1. use double quotes as ilkkachu suggests: `"s/'/\"/g"`
2. concatenate string segments: `'s/'"'"'/"/g'` or `'s/'\''/"/g'`
3. use an [ANSI-C quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting): `$'s/\'/"/g'`
4. don't quote the whole thing, escape the chars that need escaping: `s/\'/\"/g`

Answer (score 7):

For a single character change, `tr` might be quickest:

```
tr \' \" <infile >outfile
```

Note that both quotes need escaping in the shell environment. Or for replacing in the same file, use `sponge` (from `moreutils` package)

```
tr \' \" <infile | sponge infile
```