# sed is not working as expected for a string with quotes

Tags: sed

I need to change  's3_bucket': 'pass' to hello
but it is not working

ex:
`echo "'s3_bucket': 'pass'" | sed 's/'s3_bucket':/hello/'` 
outputs:
's3_bucket': 'pass'

Please help understand what am I doing wrong

Comment: Is your data literally the output from `echo`, or are you working with a text file?  Is that text file in JSON, YAML, or HCL format? Modifying a document with `sed` when that document format requires special encoding of data is not really encouraged.  There are special tools for working with that sort of data.  Also, are you actually _querying_ the document with a password, or do you just want to modify all instances of the `s3_bucket` key?

Answer (score 3):

The quoting is wrong. The part `'s/'s3_bucket':/hello/'` is interpreted by the shell as `'s/'` followed by `s3_bucket` and `':/hello/'`, resulting in `s/s3_bucket:/hello/` as an argument for `sed`.

Try

```
echo "'s3_bucket': 'pass'" | sed "s/'s3_bucket':/hello/"
```

or

```
echo "'s3_bucket': 'pass'" | sed 's/'\''s3_bucket'\'':/hello/'
```

Note that in the second version there are two adjacent single quotes in `'\''`, not a double quote.

There are more possible ways of quoting, see [this answer to a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/548334/330217).