# How to escape a "\" in command parameters

Tags: bash, command-line, quoting

I have a command

```
path/to/forticlientsslvpn_cli --server <host>:<port> --vpnuser testpass\101
```

When I run the script, linux puts a space between testpass and 101. I want the script to see "testpass\101" as the username

I hope I make sense

Answer (score 10):

This is happening because `\` is an escape character.

Either use quoting

```
path/to/forticlientsslvpn_cli --server <host>:<port> --vpnuser 'testpass\101'
```

or use an escaped backslash:

```
path/to/forticlientsslvpn_cli --server <host>:<port> --vpnuser testpass\\101
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, I used the escaped backlash option.

Comment: You might want to use single quotes to protect backslashes, since they're still special for escaping some characters within double-quotes, e.g. the backslash itself. E.g. a double backslash would be either `'\\'` or `"\\\\"`.

Comment: Thanks for your addendum, I have edited the answer. @OP: Please mark the answer as "accepted" if it solved your question.

Comment: Hi, could you explain why would ``\`` add an space? I'm having trouble understand it, I think it's the same as `testpass'1'01`, where does the space come from?

Comment: @dedowsdi, there's no space. you're right `testpass\101` is the same as `testpass101`.

Answer (score 7):

For completeness, with the `bash` shell and on ASCII based systems, with quoting  alone:

- `'testpass\101'` (by far the best)
- `testpass\\101`
- `"testpass\101"` or `"testpass\\101"` (latter better)
- `$'testpass\\101'`
- `$'testpass\u005c101'` or `$'testpass\U0000005c101'` (U+005C being the Unicode code point for backslash)
- `$'testpass\x5c101'` (where 0x5C is the byte value of the ASCII encoding of `\`)
- `$'testpass\134101'` (same in octal)

For more details, see [How to use a special character as a normal one?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141)