# How to grep double quote contains backslashes in single-quote in a file?

Tags: grep

I have a file contains a line like content below

```
xxx <u2py.DynArray value=b'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'>
```

In a shell script, I want to `grep u2py.DynArray value=b'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'`
how to achieve?

I tried `grep "u2py.DynArray value=b'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'"` file, nothing returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-F` option (for *fixed-string search*, formerly done with the `fgrep` utility):

```
grep -F "u2py.DynArray value=b'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'" file
```

The `.` and `\` characters are regular expression operators, one that matches any single character, the other used to *escape* regular expression operators or introduce new ones (in front of `x` though, the behaviour is unspecified by POSIX and could vary with the implementation).

So  without `-F`, you'd need to escape both.

Since in Bourne-like shells or `fish`, inside `"..."`, `\` also has a special escaping meaning for the shell, you'd also need another round of escaping for it:

```
grep "u2py\.DynArray value=b'F\\\\xfeVOC\\\\xfeD_VOC'" file
```

In csh or tcsh, that would be:

```
grep "u2py\.DynArray value=b'F\\xfeVOC\\xfeD_VOC'" file
```

The `rc` shell and derivatives don't support `"..."` as a quoting operator. You'd need to use single quotes:

```
grep 'u2py\.DynArray value=b''F\\xfeVOC\\xfeD_VOC''' file
```

(single quotes are expressed as `''` inside single quotes there. See [How to use a special character as a normal one?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141) for more information).

Comment: thanks Stéphane, both methods working for me
for latter one, double backslash works too
grep "u2py\.DynArray value=b'F\\xfeVOC\\xfeD_VOC'" file

Comment: @xq10907, I can't see how `grep "F\xfe"` could not work but both `grep "F\\xfe"` and `grep "F\\\\xfe"` would work. What shell are you using?

Comment: it's bash, you are right,double backslashes doesn't work
grep "u2py\.DynArray value=b'F\\\\xfeVOC\\\\xfeD_VOC'" file

Comment: The shell (any bourne shell) is still waiting to raise its ugly head, try: `grep -F "u2py.DynArray value=b'F\\xfeVOC\\xfeD_VOC'" file`. It also works, meaning that the shell is removing one of the two backslash. It would be more visible trying to match two backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Either use:

```
$ cat <<\END | grep -Ff - file
u2py.DynArray value=b'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'
END
```

Or

```
$ var='u2py.DynArray value=b'"'"'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'"'"

$ grep -F -- "$var" file
xxx <u2py.DynArray value=b'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'>
```

---

It turns out the problem is with the `\` (backslash) not the `'` (quotes).
But first, a `.` needs to be quoted to be literal in a regex.

```
$ grep "u2py\.DynArray value=b'F" file
xxx <u2py.DynArray value=b'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'>
```

As you can see above, the `'` is found by grep.
But to find a \x, the change is drastic in bash:

```
$ grep "u2py\.DynArray value=b'F\\\\x" file
xxx <u2py.DynArray value=b'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'>
```

Why four `\`? Because the shell converts two `\\` to `\` and grep receiving two `\\` interprets it as one `\` as `\` is also an special character in regexes.

We can see the two steps with:

```
$ set -x; grep "u2py\.DynArray value=b'F\\\\x" file ; set +x
+ grep --color=auto 'u2py\.DynArray value=b'\''F\\x' file
xxx <u2py.DynArray value=b'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'>
+ set +x
```

We can reduce **one** level of interpretation with the `-F` option of grep.

```
$ set -x; grep -F "u2py.DynArray value=b'F\\x" file ; set +x
+ grep --color=auto -F 'u2py.DynArray value=b'\''F\x' file
xxx <u2py.DynArray value=b'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'>
+ set +x
```

Or, without `set -x`:

```
$ grep -F "u2py.DynArray value=b'F\\x" file
xxx <u2py.DynArray value=b'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'>
```

That last level of "interpretation" is difficult to remove.
And **all** Bourne shells do that. And [POSIX require it](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_02_03).

If it is possible to generate on stdout the exact string to search, we can use

```
grep -Ff - file
```

To search for the exact "Fixed string" (`-F`) from the file (`-f`) standard input (`-`) inside `file`.

This might **seem** to work:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "u2py.DynArray value=b'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'"
u2py.DynArray value=b'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'
```

But no, the shell is still waiting to remove backslashes:

```
printf '%s\n' "u2py.DynArray value=b'F\\\\xfeVOC\\\\xfeD_VOC'"
u2py.DynArray value=b'F\\xfeVOC\\xfeD_VOC'
```

The only robust way to avoid the backslash removal is to use a here document.
Ugly syntax, but works pretty well.

```
$ cat <<\END
u2py.DynArray value=b'F\xfeVOC\\\\xfeD_VOC'
END
```

Please note the use of `\END` (the `END` **is** quoted).
And the command then becomes:

```
$ cat <<\END | grep -Ff - file
u2py.DynArray value=b'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'
END
```

With a var there is no need for a here document **once** the var has the correct value:

```
$ var='u2py.DynArray value=b'"'"'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'"'"

$ grep -F -- "$var" file
xxx <u2py.DynArray value=b'F\xfeVOC\xfeD_VOC'>
```

Alternatively could be `grep -Fe "$var" file`. Thanks @StéphaneChazelas.