# How to pass brackets to some program's arguments?

Tags: bash, command-line, syntax

I am trying to execute the command like this

```
python train.py --conv-layers [(512, 10, 5), (512, 8, 4)]
```

but bash swears

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I need `train.py` receive exactly this.

How to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[`, `(` and SPC are all special characters in the syntax of the `bash` shell. See how the SPC in between `python` and `train.py` for instance was used to delimit two arguments to pass to `/path/to/python`. `[`/`]` are special as a glob operator, `(`, `)` are part of many constructs such as `func () ...`, `<(...)`, `(subshell)`, `((arith))`, etc.

To remove their special meaning, you use quoting/escaping. Quoting operators vary between shells. See [How to use a special character as a normal one?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141) for details.

In the `bash` shell, you can use `'...'`, `"..."`, `$'...'`, and backslash. Here, best with:

```
python train.py --conv-layers '[(512, 10, 5), (512, 8, 4)]'
```

If you intend for `[(512, 10, 5), (512, 8, 4)]` to be passed as one single argument to `/path/to/python` (beside `python`, `train.py` and `--conv-layers`).