# The old ticks vs parentheses issue: confused

Tags: bash, shell, command-substitution

Since being corrected many years ago, I switched from backticks to $() for command expansion.

But I still prefer the backticks. It is fewer keystrokes and does not involve the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

I understand that the parentheses are preferable because it is less prone to the errors that backticks is prone to, but what is the reason for the rule to *never* use backticks?

Comment: See also [How to use a special character as a normal one?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/296147). backticks can only be used portably and reliably in scalar variable assignments.

Comment: Apart from technical issues: I just got fed up with posting solutions with `...` where people just put them in as single quotes or double quotes or UTF-8 apostrophes, and then badmouthed me for posting solutions that didn't work when I knew I had tested them. $( .. ) is a visual trigger when you are debugging, where you might not eyeball back-ticks. I even saw a malicious post on LinixMint forum where somebody hid `rm -rf *` as an arg to a complex command line in an answer.

Comment: Personally, I started using $() when I realized that typing $(!!) involved much less twiddling the shift key than \`!!\`. That, and the occasional nested usage.

Comment: Answers to [What's the difference between $(stuff) and `stuff`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5778) also tackle the issue.

Comment: There's no such "rule" to never use backticks. But avoid using backticks when posting on unix.se, unless you deliberately want to trigger some people.

Comment: I prefer using $() over backticks because it makes the code look cleaner to me.

Comment: The main reason to not use backticks in the code is that they are for code highlighting here.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I agree that in scripts the parens is much preferred, but I'm thinking of the case of the quick one-liner, on the fly. I should have made that more clear in the question and would add it in now, but there have been many interesting comments to my unclear question so...

Comment: To give some perspective on "It is fewer keystrokes and does not involve the shift key.": Using a German Windows keyboard with a Mac, to type a backtick I have to press Shift+´, and then additionally press the spacebar to cancel the creation of a grave accented character like à. To be fair, typing `$(` requires pressing Shift+4 and then Shift+8.

Comment: Meta: Backticks in comments here...: Escape a backtick by a backslash: \\`

Answer (score 48):

[The Bash FAQ gives a number of reasons](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) to *prefer* parentheses to backticks, but there isn’t a universal rule that you *shouldn’t ever* use backticks.

The main reason to prefer parentheses in my view is that parsing inside `$()` is consistent with parsing performed outside, which isn’t the case with backticks. This means that you can take a shell command and wrap it with `"$()"` without much thought; that’s not true if you use backticks instead. This cascades, so wrapping a command which itself contains a substitution is easily done with `"$()"`, not so with backticks.

Ultimately I think it’s a question of habit. If you choose to use backticks for simple cases, parentheses for others, you’ll have to make that choice every time you want to substitute a command. If you choose to always use parentheses, you never have to think about it again.

The latter can explain the presence of a “don’t use backticks” rule in certain coding guides: it simplifies development, and removes a source of errors for developers and reviewers. It also explains why using parentheses can be recommended even for one-liners: it’s hard to ingrain a habit for script-writing when it’s not applied everywhere.

(As far as keying goes, that depends on the keyboard layout; on my AZERTY keyboard, `$()` doesn’t involve any shifting, whereas backticks are quite painful to write.)

Answer (score 20):

Personally, I would use `$(...)`, always, just because it's more consistent in the corner cases of nested quotes and expansions, and I like the idea of having expansions start consistently with a dollar sign, and the parenthesis are more visible than backticks which are rather light in some fonts, and can get confused with single quotes like [mentioned in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612322/the-old-ticks-vs-parens-issue-confused#comment1143328_612322). But other than the first, those are about looks and aesthetics, so your opinion may well differ.

Based on the discussion in [Have backticks (i.e. `cmd`) in *sh shells been deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126927/170373), it doesn't seem that support for backticks would be on track to be removed, so that's not a reason to say "never".

However, note that the parsing of backticks works oddly in some cases. Having to add extra backticks for nested expansions is rather simple:

```
echo `echo \`echo foo\` `
```

But that's not all. As Stéphane notes in [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296147/170373) to
[How to use a special character as a normal one?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141/170373), even nesting double quotes with backticks in the between fails in ksh, for example (I'll reproduce this one here for easier access):

```
ksh$ echo "`date +"%F %T"`"  
ksh: : cannot execute [Is a directory]
2020-10-01 %T
```

and you have to escape the inner double quotes too, even though this *looks like* it would be unambiguous to parse even without them:

```
ksh$ echo "`date +\"%F %T\"`"  
2020-10-01 14:14:27
```

(The quotes around the command substitution are relevant because of command substitution, though not with `echo` here.)

So, while this does seem like a case of "never say never", and while backticks work fine in the simple cases, I think there's enough to **strongly suggest** just using `$()` instead. :)

Comment: Simplifying nested expressions is very important.  Also huge:  avoiding backslashes as much as possible, by pretty much whatever means necessary.  Escaping metacharacters and escaping escape characters is a great recipe for confusion, unreadable and incomprehensible code, and bugs including security holes.