# How to deal with special characters in docker registry credential in new version of kubectl

Tags: variable-substitution, kubernetes

Today I want to add a docker registry credential in kubernetes v1.21.3 (it works fine in lower version of kubernetes but have problem in new version of kubernetes):

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred \
--docker-server=registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com \
--docker-username=docker654321 \
--docker-password=$balabala123 \
--docker-email=foo@gmail.com \
-n reddwarf-pro
```

but it tell me:

```
error: either --from-file or the combination of --docker-username, --docker-password and --docker-server is required
```

what should I do to add docker registry crediential into this cluster? This is the version info:

```
[root@k8smasterone ~]# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.3", GitCommit:"ca643a4d1f7bfe34773c74f79527be4afd95bf39", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-07-15T21:04:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.2", GitCommit:"092fbfbf53427de67cac1e9fa54aaa09a28371d7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T12:53:14Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 1):

**The root of the problem**

The `--docker-password` argument was supplied a value which contained a [Shell special character](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) - the `$`. The shell, which pre-processes the command line arguments *before* they are passed to the actual program (`kubectl`) therefore [mistook](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) the statement `$balabala123` as referring *to a shell variable named `balabala123`* and replaced it with the content of that shell variable. But there was no such shell variable or (environment variable) defined, so the string `$balabala123` was replaced with "nothing", and `kubectl` instead saw:

```
--docker-password= \
```

The reason for the error message is that

**The solution**

[Escape the special character](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141/377345): In the current setting, the `$` is the only character special *to the shell*, so we only need to escape this one.

```bash
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred \
--docker-server=registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com \
--docker-username=docker654321 \
--docker-password=\$balabala123 \
--docker-email=foo@gmail.com \
-n reddwarf-pro
```

The same problem was also dicussed [on the kubernetes bug report forum](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/46).

Comment: it is helpful to know how shell parse the command but I obviously did not know. So it hard to aware of some implicit problem.@AdminBee So I just tried to escape the special `$` and it works, I also did not know any more, why the `@` not escape and works?

Comment: The `@` is in no way special to the shell and therefore does not need escaping or quoting.  Personally, I would recommend single-quoting  strings containing special characters (`--docker-password='$balabala123'`) rather than escaping individual characters (which works, but which makes for ugly code and which is fiddly).