# How do I pass the contents of a multiline file as an argument?

Tags: bash, command-line, files, io-redirection, xargs

I'm trying to run a script that takes a `-t` argument. This argument stands for text, and the value -- in theory -- is allowed to be multiline. On the command line, I assume a Here Document would work, but I don't like typing out long things on the command line. In addition, I want this file to persist so I can pass it again later.

I'm not sure how to do this; if I `cat foo | xargs echo`, it prints as one line. This fixes that: `cat foo | xargs -d='' echo`, but it makes me think there are things I don't understand that will change the whitespace or general structure of the document depending on its contents.

How do I pass a multiline file as an argument without having to worry about special chars or changing its format?

Comment: There are "here documents" but I have never heard of "from documents". It looks like you just need `some-command -t "$(cat foo)"`

Comment: @muru lol, sorry that's what I meant. To me that name is so arbitrary I can never remember it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xargs -d=''` (where `-d` is an extension of the GNU implementation of `xargs`) is the same as `xargs -d=` as `''` is just quoting syntax in the shell language. That tells `xargs` to use `=` as the delimiter.

So for instance `echo foo=bar | xargs -d= cmd` would call `cmd` with `foo` and `bar<newline>` as arguments.

With `xargs -d ''` or `xargs --delimiter=` (which can be abbreviated to `xargs --del=` and even `xargs --d=` in current versions of `xargs` as there's currently no other long-option that starts with `d`), you'd get a syntax error.

You could use `xargs -d '\0'`, that would be the same as the more portable (though still not standard) `xargs -0`, which uses the NUL character as delimiter. NUL characters are not meant to appear in text files and anyway can't be passed in an argument to a non-builtin¹ command as the arguments are passed as NUL-delimited strings to the `execve()` system call.

So:

```
xargs -I'<TEXT>' -0a file cmd -t '<TEXT>' other args
```

(`-a` being another GNU `xargs` extension), would pass the exact content of `file` as  argument to `cmd -t`².

But if `file` contains a `foobar` *line* for instance, that would pass the whole line including the line delimiter (`"foobar\n"`).

Alternatively, you could do (in POSIX-like shells):

```
cmd -t "$(cat file)" other args
```

Command substitution does strip all the trailing newline characters from the output of the inside command, so would likely be preferable. If the output contains NUL characters, some shells, such  as `bash` remove them (use `"$(tr -d '\0' < file)"` instead to get that behaviour in any shell).

Note that the double quotes around it are important. Without them, the expansion would be subject to *split*+*glob* (*split* only in zsh) resulting in several arguments if the file contained characters of `$IFS` (and *newline* is in the default value of `$IFS`) or wildcard characters.

In ksh, zsh or bash, you can also use `"$(<file)"` instead of `"$(cat file)"` which optimises out the execution of `cat` by reading the files by themselves (in bash, that's still done in a child process though).

In `zsh`, you can also use the `$mapfile` special associative array in the `zsh/mapfile` module:

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
cmd -t "$mapfile[path/to/file]" other args
```

That's passing the contents as-is, including NULs (which would cause `execve()` to truncate the arg after the first NUL) and trailing newline characters.

In the `rc` shell or derivatives, you can do:

```
cmd -t ``(){cat file} other args
```

Where ``` ``(sep)cmd ``` is a variant of command substitution (which is `` `cmd `` there) where you specify the separator, here none. There's no stripping of trailing newlines in that shell so the whole file contents will be passed as-is.

In any case, note that on most systems, there's a limit on the total size of arguments³ to a command (though on recent versions of Linux, that limit can be raised by changing the *stack size* limit), and on Linux on the size of a single argument (128KiB max).

---

Now, to pass a multiline string literally without have to worry about special characters, you can do:

```
cmd -t 'the multiline here
where the only character you have to
worry about in Bourne-like shells is 
single quote which you have to enter
as '\'', that is leave the quotes, enter
it with other quoting operators (here \)
and resume the quotes'
```

In the `rc` shell (where `'...'` is the only form of quote) or `zsh` when the `rcquotes` option is enabled, single quotes can be entered inside single quotes as `''`, for example: `cmd -t 'It''s simpler like that'`. See [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141) for the details about quoting in various shells.

Or you can use a here-document, either stored in a variable:

```bsh
multi=$(cat << 'EOF')
multiline string here, only worry would be about
an EOF line by itself though also note that
all trailing newlines, so that includes all
trailing empty lines are removed, including these:


EOF
)
cmd -t "$multi" # note the quotes again
```

Or directly as:

```
cmd -t "$(cat << 'EOF'
multi
line
here
EOF
)"
```

Note the quotes around `EOF` in those. Without them, parameter expansions (like `$var`), command substitutions (like `$(cmd)` or `` `cmd` ``) and arithmetic expansions (`$((...))`) are still performed.

In the `mksh` shell, you can use:

```
cmd -t "$(<< 'EOF'
multi
line
EOF
)"
```

Where the `cat` and fork are optimised out, making it essentially a multiline form of quotes.

---

<sup>¹ It can't be passed in the arguments of builtin commands or functions, and can't even be stored in variables with most shells as well, `zsh` being the only exception that I know.</sup>

<sup>² as long as the file is not empty. If the file is empty, with `-I`, the command is not run at all, you'd need the file to contain one NUL character for the command to be called with one empty argument.</sup>

<sup>³ technically, the limit (in the `execve()` system call again, so does not apply to shell builtins / functions) is on the cumulated size of arguments *and environment* and generally also takes into account the size of the pointers to each argument and envvar string, so it's generally difficult to predict in advance whether a particular set of arguments will break the limit.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for explaining the details of `-d=''`. I expect that to pay dividends down the line. Is it standard for `--<long-name>` to use `=` and `-<x>` to not? `Command substitution does strip all the trailing newline characters from the output of the inside command` In this case, I assume this means the newline(s) at the end of the file (as opposed to at the end of each line). LMK if I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5):

1. Why not just pass it a filename?   If the script doesn't already know how to deal with filenames, modify it so that it does (e.g. by treating all unknown arguments as filenames, and/or by adding a `-f` option for input filenames).  Remember to add error-checking code and respond appropriately when a filename doesn't exist, or can't be read due to permissions, etc.
2. Quote your argument.  e.g. `-t "$(cat foo)"`

Comment: 1. I'd like to, but the script is way over my head. I could modify it for my personal use, but I think I'd have to spend a day learning bash to contribute back to the repo. I'd rather do the latter some day ™

Comment: BTW, how do I learn *why* `"$(cat foo)"` is safe for any file contents?

Comment: @DanielKaplan *Any* file contents? No. (1) `"$(cat foo)"` removes all newlines from the very end. (2) In Bash you cannot pass NUL bytes this way. But since your script expect *text*, you shouldn't pass NUL bytes (by [definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403) the text file does not contain NUL). (3) `Argument list too long` is possible. // The right way to pass arbitrary content is not via the command line. The script should work with a file: stdin or a named file (the name specified in the command line, environment, config or hardcoded).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Agreed. I created an issue for that.