# How do you output a multi-line string that includes slashes and other special characters?

Tags: bash, shell-script, echo, escape-characters, here-document

I would like to output this on completion of my bash script.

```
 /\_/\
( o.o )
 > ^ <
```

I have tried the following but all return errors.

```
echo /\\_/\\\n\( o.o \)\n > ^ <
echo  \/\\_\/\\\r\n( o.o )\r\n > ^ <
echo /\\_/\\\n\( o.o \)\n \> ^ <
```

How do I escape these characters so that bash renders them as a string?

Comment: I can't help wondering whether there is a meaning to the output, or whether it's a [useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) 

Comment: It's probably a UUoC but as long as you aren't relying on ASCII art elsewhere in your program then it should be OK :D For me, there is no meaning to the output on this occasion, I just wanted to echo a cat on termination.

Comment: @IMSoP This is a very useful use of a cat!

Comment: I think the title should be changed (maybe?). This is something really useful for some, as the question itself is about outputting a multi-line string with slashes and white-space. However, I fail to come up with something interesting. The current title is, in my opinion, inadequate. There's no "conversion" going on, specially "to bash echo" (how does one convert something to "echo" anyway?). However, in my opinion, the title is intriguing enough to make it a very visited post. I don't know how to feel about the title...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel agreed - if you can think of a better one feel free to change it

Comment: @JamesGeddes That's my problem ... I don't have any ideas for a better title :/

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel how is that?

Comment: @JamesGeddes I'm bad at titles... What you wrote is way better than anything I can come up with.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In this case, I'd use `cat` with a (quoted) here-document:

```bsh
cat <<'END_CAT'
 /\_/\
( o.o )
 > ^ <
END_CAT
```

This is the best way of ensuring the ASCII art is outputted the way it is intended without the shell "getting in the way" (expanding variables etc., interpreting backslash escape sequences, or doing redirections, piping etc.)

You could also use a multi-line string with `printf`:

```bsh
printf '%s\n' ' /\_/\
( o.o )
 > ^ <'
```

Note the use of single quotes around the static string that we want to output. We use single quotes to ensure that the ASCII art is not interpreted in any way by the shell. Also note that the string that we output is the *second* argument to `printf`.  The first argument to `printf` is always a single quoted formatting string, where backslashes are far from inactive.

Or multiple strings with `printf` (one per line):

```bsh
printf '%s\n' ' /\_/\' '( o.o )' ' > ^ <'
```

```bsh
printf '%s\n' \
' /\_/\' \
'( o.o )' \
' > ^ <'
```

Or, with `echo` (but see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803) ; basically, depending on the shell and its current settings, there are possible issues with certain escape sequences that may not play nice with ASCII drawings),

```bsh
echo ' /\_/\
( o.o )
 > ^ <'
```

But again, just outputting it from a here-document with `cat` would be most convenient and straight-forward I think.

Comment: Love the suggestion to cat a cat :D

Comment: Or `cat << ''` or `cat << ''` :-)

Answer (score 16):

Quote it with single `''` or double quotes `""` to prevent the `<>()` from being taken as operators. Then if you want it on one line, use `echo -e` or `$' '` in Bash, mark the newlines as `\n` and escape the backslashes with another backslash. Or rather use `printf` to avoid issues with the differences between `echo` in various environments.

So:

```
$ printf ' /\\_/\\\n( o.o )\n > ^ <\n'
 /\_/\
( o.o )
 > ^ <
$ printf "%s\n" $' /\\_/\\\n( o.o )\n > ^ <'
 /\_/\
( o.o )
 > ^ <
```

See also:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)
- [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296141/how-to-use-a-special-character-as-a-normal-one-in-unix-shells)
- [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/170373)
- [What is the difference between the "...", '...', $'...', and $"..." quotes in the shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503013/170373)