# How do recursive replace of string with '?

Tags: sed, find, replace

In a zsh Terminal window under macOS, I'm trying to replace all instances of `(Y, d')` with `\opair{Y, d'}` recursively on all `.tex` files starting in the current directory.

The following seems to do nothing:

```
find . -type f -name "*.tex" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '.bak' -e "s/(Y, d')/\\opair{Y, d'}/g"
```

How do I fix this?

I did try escaping `'`(which according to the `sed` docs I've seen, does not actually require escaping), but that does not fix it.

Comment: So, seeing that you've accepted my answer, what was the problem in the end if it was not the X vs Y typo?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: The problem was escaping the `\` in `\opair`.... And I still do not understand why it does not suffice to have `\\opair`? Why is `\\\\` needed?

Comment: Because the ```\``` is special to the shell (once) so it should be ```\\``` and it is also special to sed (twice) so it should become ```\\\\```. There is a difficult to explain issue that allows ```\\\``` in some cases. @murray

Comment: So if I wanted to replace `\this` by `\that` with sed, it should be `sed -i.bak -e "s/\\\\this/\\\\that/g"` (with 4 backslashes in both strings)?

Comment: Yes, exactly, test with `echo '\this' | sed "s/\\\\this/\\\\that/g"` .... Because you used **double** quotes, exposing the ```\``` to the shell interpretation. Single qoutes work like this: `echo '\this' | sed 's/\\this/\\that/g'`

Comment: @QuartzCristal: That greatly clarifies matters for me; thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.tex' -type f -exec \
  sed -i.bak -e "s/(Y, d')/\\\\opair{Y, d'}/g" {} +
```

- You had `X` instead of `Y`
- no need for `xargs`, when you can use the standard `-exec cmd {} +` syntax instead.
- `\` needs to be escaped for the shell (still special inside double quotes) and for `sed`. Alternatively, you could do `'s/(Y, d'\'')/\\opair{Y, d'\''}/g'` or in `rc` or in `zsh` after `set -o rcquotes`, `'s/(Y, d'')/\\opair{Y, d''}/g'` as `\` is not special within singles (though the problem now shifts to how to pass `'`s to `sed`).
- for `find`, `-name` is often less expensive a test than `-type` so it's better to put it first (some `find` implementations do the reordering by themselves as an optimisation though).
- with `sed` implementations other than FreeBSD's (which is also the one found on macos), the backup suffix must be affixed to the `-i` option. On FreeBSD and macos, both `-i .bak` and `-i.bak` will work, but the latter is more portable and more future-proof as FreeBSD/macos might choose to align with other implementations in the future.

Also beware that there are a lot of characters that look the same and some that are invisible (including some control one). For instance, are you sure the space between `Y,` and `d'` is the ASCII space (U+0020) and not for instance the non-breaking space (U+00A0)? Or that `'` is the ASCII apostrophe and not U+2019, the right quote?

In `vim`, `ga` gives you information about the character under the cursor. `uconv -x name < file` gives you the name of each character in the input.

```
reveal() {
  perl -Mcharnames=full -Mopen=locale -pe 's{[^\t\n -~]}{
    sprintf "<U+%04X %s>", ord($&), charnames::viacode(ord($&))}ge' "$@"
}
```

Can be used to *reveal* (as things like `<U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE>St<U+00E9 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE>phane` for 　`Stéphane` for instance) characters other than space, tab, newline and ASCII printable ones.

Also beware that with some `find` implementations including GNU `find` on GNU systems, that `-name '*.tex'` may fail to match on file names that end in `.tex` but where the rest can't be decoded into characters in the current locale. For instance, it would skip a file called `$'St\xe9phane'` in a locale that uses UTF-8 as its character encoding as that 0xe9 byte alone can't be decoded into a character. Prefixing the command with `LC_ALL=C` would work around that.

Comment: Please explain why  `d'\''`.

Comment: @murray, see [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141) for instance.

Comment: Sorry, but that link does not help me with the specific question, namely, why `d'\''` ? What exactly is being escaped there and why?