# "*" becomes "Desktop" but not when stored in a variable

Tags: zsh

If I type `*` in the terminal, it is an alias for Desktop. But if I define a variable `x` and set it to `*`, it is not treated as such. When are certain characters treated as strings and when as operators ?
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: It has nothing to do with the _terminal_ and everything with the _shell_. You need to get familiar with the behavior of your shell (`zsh` for you, which behaves differently here than the more standard `bash`), around the keywords _patterns_, _wildcards_, _globbing_, _expansion_ etc. in order to understand what it does when it sees a `*`. Sorry but I can't give an exact explanation as I'm not familiar with `zsh`, I'm only familiar with `bash` which works differently here.

Comment: Related: [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141)

Answer (score 4):

Your shell expands `*` to the names of all files (except names that begin with "`.`") in the current directory via a mechanism called [*Filename Generation*](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) also known as *globbing* or *Pathname Expansion*.

In your case, "`Desktop`" was the first entry.

Look at `echo *`, or `ls`.

Comment: And for that glob expansion of happen upon parameter expansion, that is for the contents of `$x` to be considered a pattern (and it to be expanded to the matching file via filename generation when in list contexts), you need `$~x` or `${~x}` while a few other shells including bash do it always for any unquoted expansion which could be considered as a bug.