# escape in double and single quotation

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I am confusing why bash can escape "..." but can't escape '...'? Can some one give me a hint? Thanks

```
test@test:~$ echo "He said, \"Hello world\""
He said, "Hello world"
    
test@test:~$ echo "He said, \'Hello world\'"
He said, \'Hello world\'
```

Comment: Because that's how it's meant to be. See [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141) for the full details in various shells.

Comment: You can concatenate adjacent quoted strings, so each type of quote can quote the other. Thus `echo "single ' "'double " '` yields `single ' double "`.

Comment: Is there some concrete issue here, some goal you're trying to achieve?